# Google Cloud Tasks Push queue has stopped working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

I have 5 Cloud Tasks queues that have been working for the past few weeks. Today they have simply stopped firing off tasks.

The tasks are still placed into the queue without issue however the queue metrics are all zeroed out. The queue is located in us-central1.

The queue is not paused, the app-engine application is not disabled, and my billing account is up to date.

The only error I see on the Cloud Task Dashboard is "Could not load queue stats. Try to refresh later."

Any ideas on what's going on? I've applied for a Google support account but it looks like it will take 5 days to get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an incident on march 24 affecting the Cloud Scheduler service in the us-central1 region, impacting Cloud Tasks and Cron jobs.
This was documented by Google there: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-tasks/21001 (although they were still listing the service as fully functional more than one hour after the issue had started...)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me. Status page says it's working fine but none of my task are moving. When I click now nothing happens and there are not logs of it attempting to run on my server.

Comment: Ok good to know I'm not the only one affected. It seems to have started working again all of a sudden too.
Has this ever happened to you before? I've only been using tasks queues for about 2 months but they are integral to my application and the if tasks are significantly delayed it will negatively impact my users. I'm thinking I need a quick way to identify if this happens again and activate an automate/semi automated process to step in and handle the work the Task queues normally do.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's most likely a google problem, I have the same situation right now.
I have been bug hunting the last hour, but there seems nothing wrong. If multiple people are affected, it's probably not your fault.
Just wait and hope for the best.